# Petición AJAX en chrome,postman sirve, en el celular compilado con cordova no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

Con el siguiente código realizo una petición Ajax y todo va bien si se emplea "https://urlEjemplo.com" se ejecuta desde la web y desde una app compilada; pero si se cambia a "http://urlEjemplo.com" con el mismo código solo funciona desde el navegador  en la App sale el error de la imagen,y en la consola del navegador no tengo advertencias de recursos de origen cruzado.

`jQuery.ajax({
            url: api+"usuario/login",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            timeout: 15000, 
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            }
            })
            .done(function (resp){ 
                alert('done'+JSON.stringify(resp))
            })
            .fail(function(error) { 
                alert('fail'+JSON.stringify(error))
            })
            .always(function(resp){
            }

        );`
 
la petición desde el navegador web  funciona
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero desde un celular al compilar una App con (Jquery mobile y cordova)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Falta alguna configuración en la petición, o en el servicio se debe tener alguna configuración adicional o servidor?

Comment: la url del api que estas intentando consultar es una url en un servidor publico o la tienes en tu local?

Comment: Es una url de un servidor publico